# Is it possible to use ASP.Net web config app setting values as compiled constants?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have some web config app settings like page urls that change based on development environment and production environment.

I'd like the app settings to be embedded in some aspx files somehow during compile time without having to call the app settings from code to make sure they are using the correct page urls.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the compiler options to define your flags as:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"   
   compilerOptions="/D:FirstDefine,SecondDefine" 
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
  </compiler>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Then on your code you can use

```
#if FirstDefine
     // ... your code 
#endif
```

MSDN Reference

[C# Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: @user2864740 Yes it is a very good solution, I use it for years. Is also fast because is applied on compile time, and not check again the variables when is run. And if you change the web.config you make it recompile it, and change the code again.

Comment: which is the **best configuration** for ***high performance*** for production environment and _system.codedom section_ ?